# How to create dodge bar plot from binned/interval data in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, binning

I am new in r & trying to create a `dodge` **bar plot** on a **numerical variable**. Have `binned` that variable and trying to visualize the `counts` of it based on a `target/categorical variable` intervals.

taking `mpg` dataset for example:

**Code:**

```
library(tidyverse)

mpg %>% 
  mutate(cty_interval = cut(cty,5)) %>% 
  add_count(cty_interval) %>% 
  
  ggplot(aes(x = cty_interval, y = n, fill = as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_col(stat="identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

It's awkward to have **same counts** in bars for **different** `cyl` in the interval. Same is happening with my original dataset.

I am not sure what mistake I am making.

Comment: You want to count by the intersection of both groups `cty_interval` and `cyl` so replace your `add_count(cty_interval)` with `add_count(cty_interval, cyl)`

Comment: @qdread Yes I am looking for intersection of both groups, thanks for helping me with the code. I guess even with just `add_count(as.factor(cty))` it result's in same as `add_count(cty_interval, cyl)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always a good idea to take a look at the dataframe you are passing to ggplot to see if the data is making sense.

In your case, the dataframe is:

```
mpg %>% mutate(cty_interval = cut(cty,5)) %>% add_count(cty_interval)

   manufacturer model      displ  year   cyl trans      drv     cty   hwy fl    class   cty_interval     n
   <chr>        <chr>      <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>      <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>   <fct>        <int>
 1 audi         a4           1.8  1999     4 auto(l5)   f        18    29 p     compact (14.2,19.4]    105
 2 audi         a4           1.8  1999     4 manual(m5) f        21    29 p     compact (19.4,24.6]     46
 3 audi         a4           2    2008     4 manual(m6) f        20    31 p     compact (19.4,24.6]     46
 4 audi         a4           2    2008     4 auto(av)   f        21    30 p     compact (19.4,24.6]     46
 5 audi         a4           2.8  1999     6 auto(l5)   f        16    26 p     compact (14.2,19.4]    105
 6 audi         a4           2.8  1999     6 manual(m5) f        18    26 p     compact (14.2,19.4]    105
 7 audi         a4           3.1  2008     6 auto(av)   f        18    27 p     compact (14.2,19.4]    105
 8 audi         a4 quattro   1.8  1999     4 manual(m5) 4        18    26 p     compact (14.2,19.4]    105
 9 audi         a4 quattro   1.8  1999     4 auto(l5)   4        16    25 p     compact (14.2,19.4]    105
10 audi         a4 quattro   2    2008     4 manual(m6) 4        20    28 p     compact (19.4,24.6]     46
```

So, the `n` column shows the total number of cars in each bin (regardless of the number of `cyl`). So when you divide it by `cyl`, it shows the values in `n` (which are the same for all rows in the same bin -- compare rows 1 and 6).

It is also probably overplotting a lot of bars in the same position (since it plots one bar for each row and there is a lot of repetition). So you could simply
use `add_count(cty_interval, cyl)` (like @qdread suggested in the comment above), but this would still have this issue of overplotting the same bar over and over.

I think that the right way to do this is by using `dplyr::group_by` and `dplyr::summarise` (included in `tidyverse`). You should group by the two variables you are interested (`cty_interval` and `cyl`) and count the number of occurrences in each group with `summarise`. Also, because this will not show empty groups, I used `complete` to add rows for the empty groups (otherwise the column plot would look weird).

```
df.1 <- mpg %>% 
  mutate(cty_interval = cut(cty,5)) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(cty_interval, cyl) %>%
  summarise(n=n()) %>%
  complete(cty_interval, cyl, fill = list(n = 0))
```

Which results in:

```
   cty_interval   cyl     n
   <fct>        <int> <dbl>
 1 (8.97,14.2]      6    14
 2 (8.97,14.2]      8    59
 3 (14.2,19.4]      6    65
 4 (14.2,19.4]      8    11
 5 (19.4,24.6]      6     0
 6 (19.4,24.6]      8     0
 7 (24.6,29.8]      6     0
 8 (24.6,29.8]      8     0
```

And the plot now looks like this:

```
ggplot(data=df.1, aes(x = cty_interval, y = n, fill = as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

You can probably improve it by changing the width of the bars (I think the groups in the bins are too close to the next one and it looks confusing)

Comment: Thank you @kikoralston for putting in so much of efforts to share a in depth explanation. Really admire & appreciate it :)